# IE input file attribute is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, mozilla

I have the following input file tag:

```
<input type="file" id="handlerxhr1" />
```

In mozilla when I run the following jQuery code:

```
var input = $('#handlerxhr1')[0];
        $('#upload').click(function() {
            alert(input.files[0]);

        });
```

I get response: [object File] (which is good).

But in IE I get 'input.files.0 is undefined'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try alert(typeof(input.files)); in IE

Comment: It might be affected by the way IE handles JS differently than firefox. The click event you have putten on your upload button fires after the upload is done on firefox, and before its done on IE.

Comment: can't be. because click event i declared var input when document.ready and after it's loaded i click '#upload' button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems good enough...

```
$(function() {
    var input = $('#handlerxhr1')[0];         
    $('#upload').click(function() {             
        alert(input);          
    }); 
});
```

Not sure if your were after something like this though:

```
$(function() {
    var input = $('#handlerxhr1')[0];         
    $('#upload').click(function() {             
        var x = $('input[type=file]:eq(0)');
        alert(x);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: `$('#handlerxhr1')[0]` is the same as `$('#handlerxhr1')` because jquery returns an array of matching elements. It doesn't do the same thing as `files[0]`.

Answer (score 6):

IE doesn't support .files[0] property, whereas FF does.
See http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/ for more details

Comment: Well, what is a cross browser option?

Comment: is there any external library for handling files in IE9?