# Javascript file input issues in IE

Tags: javascript, html

How would I write the correct solution script as seen in this post: [IE input file atribute is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000950/ie-input-file-problem) without using jQuery?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just translated to JavaScript!

```
var input = document.getElementById("handlerxhr1")         
document.getElementById('upload').attachEvent('onclick', function() {             
    alert(input);          
});
```

translation of this: `var x = $('input[type=file]:eq(0)');` is:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  It was the getElementsByTagName that threw me!