# Get the list of files currently attached to the <input> element

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, input, firebug

I am wrapping some jQuery functionality around jQuery File Upload plugin. It uses an `<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple">` element to what it seems like "hook up" the selected files before the upload. When a form on which the input resides is submitted, files are parsed on the server.

In order to debug my UI, I need to see the list of files currently "attached" to the input. Is it possible with Firebug or Chrome debugger?

Comment: perhaps [this](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API) could help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can just use the console and jquery:

```
$("#idofinput")[0].files
```

Then just treat it like an array of files :)

Comment: @SarathSaleem You seem to be correct. Here is a jsfiddle (not mine) that exhibits this...http://jsfiddle.net/eq3Qv/176/

Comment: Here is a SO where this problem is brought up, but not quite addressed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000950/ie-input-file-problem

Comment: Finally, here is another SO that lists some alternatives (mainly that you have to use ActiveX)...no wonder IE sucks...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512009/how-to-get-file-size-from-clientside-using-javascript-in-ie

Comment: Correction: $("#idofinput")[0].files

'files' is a property of the element, not the jQuery object.

Comment: Can somebody please help me? I'm only able to get a single file using this but I selected multiple files. It's driving me insane!

Comment: @user2081044 you should open up a separate wuestion

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it. I just created a separate array because all the files in the input get overwritten once the user makes a different selection of images. It was a little tedious, but the user had to be able to add/delete images from a central point so I convert them to base64 and store them in a separate array and it works :)

Answer (score 7):

This is how you can check in console:

```
$("#idofinput").get(0).files
```

Comment: You rocked Man (Y) .
get() is what I was looking for :) Thank You so much!