# Detect file size before upload: NOT html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to detect the size of the file **before** upload.

I need it to work in IE8, thus not HTML5
It needs to be entirely client side.
I need to be able to specify file size limit.

I am aware that ActiveX can be used, but I cannot use that due to it requiring the user to 'permit' it.

I have tested [BlueImps plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin), but it doesn't seem to work and the documentation does not seem to state browser support.

Can anyone suggest a plugin/method with fits with my criteria.

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13512009/1300817). It seems to be in plain javascript using the `File API`, but does not work on IE.

Comment: @RoyiNamir thanks for your comment. Uploadify would be my preferred alternative. Unfortunately, appears to be dependent on PHP, which the server does not support.

Comment: @JezD _dependent on PHP_ ???

Comment: I think using flash can help to you

Comment: Uploadify is not dependent on PHP, you can freely use it with any other server side language. It doesn't do anything more than upload a certain POST request to a certain server-side address.

Comment: This is not possible without the File API or Flash / ActiveX.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Have just re-read the uploadify docs. Yep, it seems I can post to any serverside uploaded file handler

Comment: Having said that , I just tested their old version with pure ie8 ( VM) and it doesn't work... let me see if it's relates to flash installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to introduce a dependency on Flash, then you could use that to get the file size (and handle the upload too).

Flash supports file-selection via the [FileReference class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html), which gives you access to some metadata including the file size.

With some help from the [ExternalInterface class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html), you could call a JavaScript function and give it this information.

You could then upload the file from Flash instead of with the usual input element, if the file size is appropriate.

Check out [YUI's uploader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/uploader/) for a really easy-to-use and well-documented free component that handles all this for you (you only need to write a little JavaScript, and you can style the pre-built Flash component however you want).